# Cursor disappears after installing parallels tools in loki

Tags: release-loki, virtualization

pretty much the title- version 0.4/loki
 using either parallels 11 or 12, after i install parallels tools the cursor is invisible (I can still click things on the desktop)

Things i tried-
 1. Reinstalling
 2. Disable Vsync
 3. Disable 3D acceleration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set the Boot flags to this:
devices.usb.mouse=1

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This fixed it. it seems that you just need to try either 0 or 1 and see what works for you

Answer (score 1):

this fixed for me:

shutdown the vm. open configure -> Hardware -> Boot Order. expand "Advanced Options" and type the following in the text box for Boot flags:

devices.usb.mouse=0

save and start the vm.

Comment: does it matter if install before or after the boot flags